# Random walk on infinite binary tree (recurrence, transience)

Tags: markov-chains, random-walk, binary

> > Consider a random walk on the infinite binary tree with root $x$ which has the following transition probabilities.
> >     $$
> > p_{x,0}=p_{x,1}=\frac{1}{2},~~~p_{y,y0}=p,~~~p_{y,y1}=q,~~\text{and }p_{y,\tau y}=r,
> > $$
> >     for $y\in\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\left\{0,1\right\}^n=:\Sigma^*$, where $\tau\colon\Sigma^*\to\Sigma\cup\left\{x\right\}$ is defined by
> >     $$
> > \tau(y_1\cdots y_{n-1}y_n):=y_1\cdots y_{n-1}\text{ for }n\geq 2,~~\tau(0)=\tau(1):=x.
> > $$
> >     Assume that $p,q,r\geq 0$ and $p+q+r=1$.

[image: binary tree]

Determine $p,q,r$ for which the random walk is

(a) reducible,

(b) irreducible and transient and

(c) irreducible and recurrent.

---

**EDIT**

I add my new results:

(a) reducible if at least one of $p,q,r$ is $0$.

(b) irreducible and transient for

$$
r\in \left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right)\cup\left(\frac{1}{2},1\right)\text{ and } p,q\in (0,1) \text{ such that }p+q=1-r.
$$
.

(c) irreducible and recurrent for
$$
r=\frac{1}{2}\text{ and }p,q\in (0,\frac{1}{2}]\text{ such that }p+q=\frac{1}{2}.
$$

Comment: Hint: The distance from the random walk to the root is itself a random walk. Can you compute its transition probabilities?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18616/discussion-on-question-by-salamo-random-walk-on-infinite-binary-tree-recurrence).

Comment: @Did Please have a look on my new results that I edited. And please tell me if they are okay now. Tahnk you very much.

Comment: @Did I have one question: Why is the random walk on the infinite binary tree for example recurrent if the Markov chain modelling the distance is recurrent?

Comment: Because there is only one way for the distance process to be zero, which is that the Markov chain on the tree is at the root.

Comment: Ah, yes. Now I understand. I consider (for recurrence) $(1-r)^{-1}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}}(4(1-r)r)^n$ (Stirling) and this converges if $r\neq\frac{1}{2}$. See my results.

Comment: Last comment from me: you are far from the solution. Please follow the specific suggestion in one of my comments now moved to chat.